# undo git pull of wrong branch onto master

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I have **pulled from** a different branch from the remote. The 2 branches are different yet the merge happened silently on my current branch. I am currently working on the "master" branch locally, and it has been updated with the changes of the remote branch - "FE_Changes".

How do I remove the effects of the "FE_Changes" branch from my master branch ?

Comment: Are you using git inside and IDE? Terminal? or something like that?

Comment: Yes Im actually using Git Extensions. This happened when I pulled in "FE_Changes" branch while being in the "master" branch. What I should have used is the checkout dialog instead.

Comment: Can you show the output (as much as is relevant) of the following command:
git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate

assuming there's no sensitive info in the commit logs, of course... it should help clarify what happened exactly

Comment: If you are usin Git Extensions in example in jetbrains IDEs you can go to the bottom right corner and change to your branch and you will get your code in the same way. When this happen you didn't merge your results but this IDE for example do an smart merge in your code but unless you upload it to your repository changes are not made.

Comment: $ git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate
* 02dbe77 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, origin/FE_Changes, master, FE_Chang
* e98c2a3 Mutiple population fixed
* c5d6e03 FE Functions added
* 0020070 Commit
* 5d2666c Commit new files
* 772cd7d comiit
* 146c9e7 Initial Commit

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not familiar with git extensions or your IDE, but if I understand correctly, the fe_changes branches has been merged into master. have you pushed that merge to the remote yourself? if not, it looks more like someone else performed that merge, and you only pulled that merge

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

This will nuke the most recent commit on your local branch.  Assuming your pull strategy is merge, then there should only be one rogue commit on your local master branch.  You mentioned that "the merge happened silently," so this should work in your case.  Once you have fixed the master branch, you may pull again, this time making sure you pull from the correct remote branch.

Comment: wow this did it. I must say I did some crazy things on the Git Extensions GUI like checking out from origin/master, git reset (to HEAD not HEAD~1) but still this overwrote that and brought changes back. And whats more, I can now pull and get the recent updates to "master" again from remote. None of the changes done on "FE_Changes" branch is visible now in my local "master" branch. Thanks a lot Tim.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Tim's answer:
If you want to reset to a specific commit:

```
git reflog
```

will show you ids of all recent commits

[image]

Then you can perform:

```
git reset --hard <specific id>
```

to reset to that specific commit.

Answer (score 5):

You can do simply using the following commands

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the accepted answer;

**git reset --hard HEAD~1**

1. git reset

Git reset is a powerful command that is used to undo local changes to the state of a Git repo. Git reset operates on "The Three Trees of Git". These trees are the Commit History ( HEAD ), the Staging Index, and the Working Directory.

2. --hard

This is the most direct, DANGEROUS, and frequently used option. When passed, this command causes the commit history ref pointers to be updated to the specified commit. Then, the Staging Index and Working Directory are reset to match that of the specified commit. Any previously pending changes to the Staging Index and the Working Directory gets reset to match the state of the Commit Tree. This means any pending work that was hanging out in the Staging Index and Working Directory will be lost.

3. HEAD~1 or HEAD~2 or HEAD~3 etc...

Use '~' to go back a number of commits.
**HEAD~1** moves the current branch backward by one commit, effectively removing the 1 snapshot that was just created from the project history. Remember that this kind of reset should only be used on unpublished commits. Never perform the above operation if you’ve already pushed your commits to a shared repository.